# Cannot load the codeigniter pagination library

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, libraries

I am working on the codeigniter as a beginner,, and got this problem.. 
I cannotload the Pagination Library...

Here is the code

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
public function index() {

    if($this->load->library('pagination')) {
        echo "load success";
    }
    else {
        echo "load failed";
    }

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_pagination/index.php/site/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('data')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('data', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->view('site_view', $data);
}

}

?>
```

I even tried autoloading pagination library.. But still it is echoing 'Load Failed' .
CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME???????? plzzzzzz

Comment: And what does it say? What error you get?

Comment: No, its not error. Actually it is not loading the pagination library, that's is why it is not displaying the pagination links.
Actually, this code
 
    if($this->load->library('pagination')) {
        echo "load success";
    }
    else {
        echo "load failed";
    }

is outputting 'load failed'. So, that's why i guessed may be the pagination library is not loading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your code, load function does not return boolean value (it returns NULL or error), therefore your `if()` statement is always `false`, in fact you can check in CodeIgniter logs after you turn on `log_threshold` config value to `2` - DEBUG.

It looks like this:

```
DEBUG - 2015-01-11 16:51:11 --> Pagination Class Initialized
```

testing code I am working with:

```
public function pagination() {
    var_dump( $this->load->library('pagination') );
}
```

Further more you want this line in your view file instead of controller itself.

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

---

**Please do your [homework](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) before asking here next time.**